# Accuracy and F1 score for binary classification

Tags: classification, precision-recall

Consider a binary classification, where the precision is 1 for one class and the recall is 1 for the other class. Thus, all false classifications are some elements of class 1 being detected as class 2. Is there any relationship between accuracy and average F1 score in this case? I've noticed that they are the same in some cases I've seen. However, the number of samples were low in these cases. Also the classes were in a ratio of 80:20. [Average F1 score here is the F1 scores of the two classes weighted by the number of elements in each class].